# Trying to get conjure 2.6.1 but not getting

Tags: conjure-up, kubernetes

```
 vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo snap remove conjure-up   
 Stop snap "conjure-up" services /Discard interface connections for snap "conjure-up" (1015)    
 -conjure-up removed   
 vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic    
 Fetch and check assertions for snap "conjure-up" (1015)   
 /Fetch and check assertions for snap "conjure-up" (1015)                     
 -Fetch and check assertions for snap "conjure-up" (1015)                     
 \Fetch and check assertions for snap "conjure-up" (1015)                     
 |Fetch and check assertions for snap "conjure-up" (1015)                     
 /Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                          
 -Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                           
 \Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                           
 |Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                           
 /Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                          
 -Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                           
 \Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                           
 |Mount snap "conjure-up" (1015)                                           
 /Setup snap "conjure-up" (1015) security profiles     
 -Setup snap "conjure-up" (1015) security profiles     
 \Run configure hook of "conjure-up" snap if present       
 |conjure-up 2.6.0-20180705.1607 from 'canonical' installed    
 vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ conjure-up --version   
 conjure-up 2.6.0   
 vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the resolution, got it working by below command:

```
sudo snap refresh conjure-up --edge
```